# How display video with Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv
capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
cv.NamedWindow("capture", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')
fps = 25
w, h = 640, 480
stream = cv.CreateVideoWriter("test.avi", fourcc, fps, (w, h))
while True:
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.WriteFrame(stream, frame)
    cv.ShowImage("capture", frame)
```

This code only save video, but frame with video cannot open

Comment: add `cv.WaitKey(10)` after `cv.ShowImage`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `WaitKey` function after calling `ShowImage`. Quoting from OpenCV wiki:

> Note: This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and
>   handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing, unless HighGUI is used within some environment that takes
>   care of event processing.